# Prevent ignored conversation from processing rules

Tags: microsoft-outlook

I have several rules set up in Outlook to route messages to different folders based on subject line, content, etc. Sometimes from a folder I will ignore a conversation. My goal is to never see any more messages in that thread anymore - not in the inbox or in that folder.

Yet the messages are still showing in the folder. On follow up messages, the ignore conversation button is depressed, showing that Outlook knows it is ignored. If I press that button, it *un*-ignores the conversation.

How can I prevent seeing ignored messages which have had automatic rules applied on them?

Comment: Cannot understand your issue very well. According to my test, when you have already ignored a conversion, the new incoming emails of this conversion will not go to the rule-setting location, but will directly go to the Deleted Items folder.

Comment: Thx. That is what I am hoping would happen. In my case, the message is automatically moved to a folder when received. I hit ignore on it in that folder, and it goes to deleted. Then another message in the thread arrives, and instead of going to deleted items, it is sent to the folder by the rules.

Answer (score 1):

It seems work well in my environment Outlook 365 Version 2002(Build 12527.21416). Please make sure you have upgraded your Outlook to the latest version. Maybe you could try the [Office repair](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/repair-an-office-application-7821d4b6-7c1d-4205-aa0e-a6b40c5bb88b), then [create and use a new Outlook profile](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/create-an-outlook-profile-f544c1ba-3352-4b3b-be0b-8d42a540459d) to see if there is any difference.